# How to know what name to type to launch a program after installing it with yum/rpm?

Tags: package-management, yum, rpm

I just installed a `rpm` using the following command:

```
yum localinstall ./FoxitReader-1.1-0.fc9.i386.rpm
```

Now, this did the trick and I could launch the app using:

```
FoxitReader &
```

What if `FoxitReader` failed to launch the app and the name was something else. How could I find out what the name of launcher file could be that just got installed?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I usually list out the contents of the RPM and filter it using `/bin/`. The files in that directory are executable.

```
$ rpm -ql ImageMagick | grep /bin/
/usr/bin/animate
/usr/bin/compare
/usr/bin/composite
/usr/bin/conjure
/usr/bin/convert
/usr/bin/display
/usr/bin/identify
/usr/bin/import
/usr/bin/mogrify
/usr/bin/montage
/usr/bin/stream
```

Comment: I am getting `package FoxitReader-1.1-0.fc9.i386.rpm is not installed` Is that because I used yum localinstall to do the install ?

Comment: `rpm -ql FoxitReader | grep bin/` - don't use the full filename of the RPM.

Comment: Thanks could you tell me why we did'nt use the full name of the rpm file ?

Comment: Because different options to the `rpm` command have different semantics.  Some expect the name of an installed package, others that of a physical file.

Comment: You can use `rpm -qlp FoxitReader-1.1-0.fc9.i386.rpm` to list the files in an RPM, `rpm -qlf /usr/share/misc/magic` to find the other files from an installed package, `rpm -qla` for all installed files, etc.

Answer (score 7):

The same for Debian; for an installed package,

```
dpkg -L <packagename> | grep -F /bin/
```

`dpkg -L` lists out the package's contents (basically prints `/var/lib/dpkg/info/<packagename>.list`) and the `grep` picks out any file paths containing `/bin/`.

For a `deb` file which you have not yet installed,

```
dpkg-deb -c path/to/filename.deb | grep -F /bin/
```

For an unfamiliar package, you usually also want to examine `/usr/share/doc/<packagename>/README.Debian` and if the directory contains other useful stuff, such as a `NEWS` file or an `examples` or `contrib` subdirectory, look at those, too.

Comment: `dpkg -S` **searches** packages containing that name. It just happens that packages usually contain a file matching its name. You really want `dpkg -L`

Answer (score 2):

As several others already have stated, look for "/bin" in the packages file list.

Here's Gentoo

`$ equery f firefox | grep bin`

`equery` is part of the package `gentoolkit`.

Answer (score 1):

With:

```
rpm -qlp package.rpm
```

command you can list files inside a rpm file. Executables probably will be in some bin folder. So:

```
rpm -qlp package.rpm | grep bin
```

can work too.